# Fonts from my website don't show up on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, github, github-pages

My Website that I'm hosting on Github Pages with a namecheap domain, doesn't allow iOS users (haven't tried android) to see the fonts. I've tried this on iOS 14.3 on an iPhone 7 with both Safari, and Chrome

The font displayed on my Windows 10 Computer is Calibri but on iOS it shows up as Times New Roman (default)

my website is http://joswinjohn.me,

html file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joswinjohn/joswinjohn.github.io/master/index.html

css file is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joswinjohn/joswinjohn.github.io/master/css/style.css

the repo is https://github.com/joswinjohn/joswinjohn.github.io if you need anything else

if there's anything I've left out please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows device is correctly displaying your "Calibri" font because that font is already installed on the device. To use a font that is not installed in the target device, you need to include the font file itself and reference it in your CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Calibri;
  src: url("Calibri.ttf") format("truetype"), url("Calibri.otf") format("opentype"), url("Calibri.woff") format("woff"), url("Calibri.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

In `src` you can use 1 or more `url()`s. If you use more than one, the browser will use the first match, or the first one it supports. Make sure what is inside `url()` matches your font file's path.